# Asynchronous multiple Web Service requests with ordered result

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Given a certain number of request objects (max 9), i need to call a web service endpoint the same number of times asynchronously. With `.NET 4.0`, we used `delegate` and `IAsyncResult` to achieve this.

Is there a better way to do this with `asyc/await`, `TPL` or both of them combined with `.NET 4.6.1`?

Will using `Parallel.ForEach` with `ConcurrentBag` be optimal as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610868/how-do-i-collect-return-values-from-parallel-foreach)?

Synchronous Code Example:

```
public List<WbsResponse> GetWbsResults()
{
    List<WbsRequest> requests = CompileWbsRequests();
    List<WbsResponse> results = new List<WbsResponse>();
    foreach (var request in requests)
    {
        //Call same web service endpoint n number of times
        var response = CallWebService(request);
        results.Add(response);
    }

    //do something with results

    return results;
}

private WbsResponse CallWebService(WbsRequest request)
{
    //Call web service
}
```

**Edit/Update 1**: Based on @Thierry's answer, i've created a sample code assuming there's an `Order` property in both the request and response objects to mark the request/response ordering:

```
public List<WbsResponse> GetWbsResults()    
{        
    List<WbsRequest> requests = CompileWbsRequests();
    List<WbsResponse> results = new List<WbsResponse>();

    Parallel.ForEach(requests, (request) => {
        var response = CallWebService(request);
        response.Order = request.Order;
        results.Add(response);
    });

    results = results.OrderBy(r => r.Order).ToList();

    //do something with results

    return results;
}

private WbsResponse CallWebService(WbsRequest request)
{
    //Call web service
}
```

**Edit/Update 2**: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102966/parallel-foreach-vs-task-run-and-task-whenall) thread, i've made a few changes to Update 1:

```
await Task.Run(() => {
    Parallel.ForEach(requests, (request) => {
        var response = CallWebService(request);
        response.Order = request.Order;
        results.Add(response);
    });
});
```

Requirement Summary:

- Make multiple web service requests asynchronously to the same endpoint with different parameters.
- Add web service results to a list in the same order as the request was made (as if it was synchronous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each task finish with diffrent moment, I think you should numero the request and ordered the responses by this numero.

In the request, you init a numero and pass this numero for the response associated. Finally, when I have the results, I order it.
Like this:

```
    public async Task<List<WbsResponse>> GetWbsResults()
    {
        List<WbsRequest> requests = CompileWbsRequests();
        List<Task<WbsResponse>> tasks = new List<Task<WbsResponse>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < requests.Count; i++)
        {
            var task = new Task<WbsResponse>(() => { CallWebService(WbsRequest); });
            tasks.Add(task);
        }
        var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var responsesOrdered = responses.OrderBy(r => r.Order)

        //do something with results

        return results;
    }  



    public List<WbsRequest> CompileWbsRequests()
    {
        //create requests
        foreach(var request in requests)
        {
            request.Order += 1;
        }
    }


    private WbsResponse CallWebService(WbsRequest request)
    {
        //Call web service

        reponse.order = request.order;
        return reponse;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use await without async

Comment: @SirRufo : Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: My C# compiler only accepts `async void` or `async Task` or `async Task<>` - maybe you have a special one

Comment: @SirRufo non, you were totally right, it should always async because I wrote the code directly on StackOverflow without a compiler with juste the idea how to work. I missed async, it's my mistake :)

Comment: `async List<WbsResponse>` will never compile but `async Task<List<WbsResponse>>` would

Comment: @ThierryV i've updated my question with a sample code based on your code. It looks cleaner than the `Task` based code. However, i'm not sure if this is efficient.

Comment: @SangSuantak I believe that it should work because ``Task.WhenAll(tasks)`` gives you an array of all task executed. With a simple order by, the results should be in order.

Comment: @ThierryV, i've made further updates to my question based on another source. Will accept your answer since it pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Task.WaitAll` to make the code work in async way and it will look prettier as well:

```
public List<WbsResponse> GetWbsResults()
{
    List<WbsRequest> requests = CompileWbsRequests();
    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(requests.Select(CallWebService));
    return responses;
}
```

but you have to modify this method as below to return a task:

```
private async Task<WbsResponse> CallWebService(WbsRequest request)
{
    //Call web service
}
```

Comment: This will never compile

Comment: @SirRufo forgot to change the other method, now I think its compiled even thought i did not try it yet

Comment: This doesn't ensure ordered results as the WhenAll just runs all the tasks in parallel

Comment: Nope, it still will never compile

Comment: Thanks for the response @RajmondBurgaj, but if it doesn't return results in order like Ulbo said, it would not solve my problem.